# Invalid swagger.json

Tags: java, spring, jersey, swagger

I followed instruction described here:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/swagger-core-jersey-1.x-project-setup-1.5

I have Jersey 1 and Spring. In pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.21</version>
</dependency>  
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.11</version>
</dependency>
```

I need to add reflections newer version, otherwise swagger won't scan and throw error. By the way, I've tested with swagger-jersey-jaxrs 1.5.0 and even 1.3.8, same result.

I use Spring Bean method (jersey config was tested also, same result) and when I access swagger.json I got following response:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "This is a app.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "title": "Swagger Test",
    "contact": {
      "name": "test@test.com"
    },
    "license": {
      "name": "Apache 2.0",
      "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
    }
  },
  "host": "https://test.com:8003",
  "basePath": "/",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ]
}

{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "This is a app.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "title": "Swagger Test",
    "contact": {
      "name": "test@test.com"
    },
    "license": {
      "name": "Apache 2.0",
      "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
    }
  },
  "host": "https://test.com:8003",
  "basePath": "/",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ]
}
```

If I add annotation to rest API, it's picked up by swagger. The only issue is `swagger.json` includes two same json bodies and make the response invalid.

Where the problem could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a custom servlet? Also are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Not custom servlet, it’s jersey servlet  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>. No spring boot

Comment: Do add the full servlet in the question.

Comment: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>service</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>

  <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>
                  com.test.rest.resource
            </param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

Do you know where is source code to generate swagger.json?

Comment: I found issue in a filter.

Comment: Hello Wendy. I have recently implemented swagger without spring using swagger-jaxrs just as you have done. If you can update your question *properly* with all necessary information I will be more than happy to help you out.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thank you very much! I found an issue in my own filter when dispatch request, I fixed it, now swagger is working with or without spring.

Comment: Great to hear. Either you can answer your own question or delete it as you have already solved it :)

Comment: How to delete it?

Comment: There's a delete option below the question. See [How to delete a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: Hi Nicholas, I don't have delete option. If you are able to delete, please delete for me. Thanks!